# MySQL query for specific year and category

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I think it's hard to find my Edit on my older post so I make a new thead:

After solving this so fast I tried to play a bit around to train on SQL a bit. Now I try to make the same as earlier, just instead of countries/regions, I want 'categories' in there(post before was about making a query where I can see the netamount of sales for the US and rest of the World for the years 2007 and 2008 in the database, now i try to make it with year and categories which begin with the letter 'A')  As I tried to make such a query I totally lost myself in it O.o 
I think I need to show the entities beforehand: 
(Over the line = tablename)

- Categories

  ---
- Category
- Categoryname
- Products

  ---
- ProdID
- Category
- Title
- Actor
- Price
- orderlines

  ---
- orderid
- orderlineid
- Prodid
- orders

  ---
- orderid
- orderdate
- customerid
- netamount

my query so far: (absolute no sense behind it :/ )

```
SELECT year(orderdate) AS YEAR,
       categoryname,
       sum(custamot)Totsales FROM
  (SELECT o.orders, sum(netamount) custamot, c.categoryname
   FROM products o
   JOIN categories c ON o.category = c.category
   WHERE categoryname LIKE 'A%'
   GROUP BY c.categoryname) iv
GROUP BY YEAR(orderdate);
```

Comment: what's wrong in that query...

Comment: @Rahul, He is referencing orderdate in his SELECT yet never selects from or joins to the orders table, so it won't work for that reason alone. Also o.orders is meaningless as o is the products table and this doesn't have a column called orders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need a subquery at all. Just join all the tables you need and write a suitable group by clause for your aggregation. You'll end up with something like:

```
SELECT YEAR(o.orderdate) AS YEAR,
       c.Categoryname,
       SUM(o.netamount) AS Totsales
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN orderlines ol ON ol.orderid = o.orderid
INNER JOIN Products p ON p.ProdID = ol.Prodid
INNER JOIN categories c ON c.Category = p.Category
WHERE c.Categoryname LIKE 'A%'
GROUP BY c.Categoryname, YEAR(o.orderdate);
```